# Is grout faulty if it has some color variation, or just drying out?

Tags: bathroom, grout

hi just had my new bathroom installed and tiled the tile used Ivory grout but when I am looking at 3 days later most of it is Ivory but there are a few cream areas in grout not sure if it is still drying or it is faulty

Comment: Most likely it's faulty,but it would help if we could see the picture.Can you post some?

Comment: Can you scrape a little bit of the top layer of each?  Do they have the same color underneath?

Answer (score 1):

It's important that the installer mixes the grout very well. Pigments can be unevenly distributed in the dry compound. After 3 days I'd suspect this as the culprit, assuming that the bath hasn't seen any use yet.

Answer (score 0):

If the wrong colour of grout was used in just some parts of your job, you're going to have a tough time replacing it, as grout often doesn't like to stick to grout.  The advice I've gotten in similar situations is to remove *all* the grout, and re-grout from scratch with the right colour, since colour-matching will be so difficult.

At Home Depot here in Canada, they sell a product called [*"Grout Renew"*](http://www.homedepot.ca/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SearchView?langId=-15&Ntt=grout+renew&Nty=1&D=grout+renew&Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&Dx=mode+matchallpartial&s=true).  It's like a thick paint, and can be applied to existing (clean) grout to change its colour.  I'm not sure how well it would work in your bathroom, but I've had great success with it on the grout in the backspash behind our kitchen sink.  I applied it with a toothbrush.

Comment: chances that someone used another type of grouting on just a part of the wall are weak (but I've seen crazier things).Plus like OP described it is happening on several places, so I really don't think that this is the case. According to my opinion either grout has expired, or there are some leaks in water system.